# Understanding how to use ARM PSA cryoto API for implementing TLS-like protocols

Tags: ssl, arm

ARM has recently announced [ARM PSA cryoto API](https://armmbed.github.io/mbed-crypto/html/index.html). Is there some resource like tutorial or paper describing how to implement a security protocol like TLS by using ARM PSA cryoto API?